# Why are alerts still coming if a job is commented out in cron?

Tags: cron

In `cron` entry I have disabled the ignite recovery tape backup. But still we are getting alerts as:

```
The action /opt/osit/omniback/bin/check_make_recovery.pl failed
```

Crontab entry :

```
# Ignite recovery tape
#30 22 * * 2 /opt/osit/omniback/bin/make_recovery_script.sh > /dev/null 2>&1
```

What's the reason for this? Can you help me stop these alerts?

Comment: How have you disabled then entry ? What you posted does not look disabled at all.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen the `#` in front of the 30 makes it a comment. Laksmi: are you sure this is the only crontab that holds this lime? Did you check users crontab and the admins one?

Comment: I did not see the # in the original post.